# PGFPLOT: Two identical y-axes on Semilogy plot

Tags: tikz

I'm trying to get two identical y-axes on a pgfplot. Essentially, repeat the left-side y-axis on the right side of the plot.  But the scaling of the right y-axis is way off. And, there are no minor tick marks at log positions on the right side y-axis. And, extra tick marks are plotted on x axis even though "axis x line = none" on second plot. What am I missing? Here's the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{semilogyaxis}[%
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    ymin = 1e0,ymax = 1e4,
    yticklabels = {10$^0$,10$^2$,10$^3$,10$^4$},
    xmin=-365,xmax=7665,
    xtick={-365,365,1095,1825,2555,3285,4015,4745,5475,6205,6935,7665},
    minor xtick={0,730,1460,2190,2920,3650,4380,5110,5840,6570,7300},
    xticklabels={2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2010,2012,2014,2016,2018,2020,2022},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
        rotate=45,
        yshift=-0.1cm,
        anchor=east}
]

\end{semilogyaxis}%

\begin{semilogyaxis}[
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line*=none,
  ymin=1e0, ymax=1e4,
  xticklabels=none,
  yticklabels = {10$^0$,10$^2$,10$^3$,10$^4$}
 ]

\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I believe the main problem was not including the xmin and xmax on the second axis definition (look for the 'special sauce' comment in the coding.  Here is my version of your minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xmode=normal,
    ymode=log,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    ymin = 1e0,ymax = 1e4,
    yticklabels = {10$^0$,10$^2$,10$^3$,10$^4$},
    xmin=-365,xmax=7665,
    xtick={-365,365,1095,1825,2555,3285,4015,4745,5475,6205,6935,7665},
    minor xtick={0,730,1460,2190,2920,3650,4380,5110,5840,6570,7300},
    xticklabels={2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,2010,2012,2014,2016,2018,2020,2022},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
        rotate=45,
        yshift=-0.1cm,
        anchor=east},
        ]
\end{axis}%
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=normal,
    ymode=log,
  axis y line*=right,
  axis x line*=none,
 % The 'special sauce'!
  xmin=-365,xmax=7665,
  ymin=1e0, ymax=1e4,
  xticklabels=none,
  yticklabels = {10$^0$,10$^2$,10$^3$,10$^4$},
  ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I couldn't get the "semilogyaxis" version to work, but that's not my usual way of doing things.  Adding the xmin and xmax line to the 2nd set of your coding fixed the y spacing so the left and right hand side lined up, but there were things going on along the x axis I couldn't explain.

What I end up with are identical axes on the left and right hand sides, with minor tick marks.  I believe the lower x axis looks correct.

I think this does what you're looking for. This is a part of what I'm trying to do today, so hopefully this is useful to you.